# I want to get Closing price of Pinnacle odds

Tags: vba, pinnacle-cart

I am now developing some application with Excel VBA
and I want to get the final result ( closing price ) of special Odds
is there anybody who can help me on this ?
Thank you.

Comment: your question is like this one ..... `i need help to paint the house on the corner of the street where my brother lives.  can anybody help me?`

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have a Table, named `Table1` and needs final result of Column named `closing price`.

Seems you need final result of odd `closing price` column. But if you need check been odd of some value else, put refer to that value in this part of the code: `([table1].Cells(i, [table1[closing price]].Column).Value)` in `If` criteria line.

Thus we have below:

```
Sub Sum_Odds()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Final As Double

    If ([table1].Cells(i, [table1[closing price]].Column).Value) Mod (2) = 1 Then
        Final = Final + [table1].Cells(i, [table1[closing price]].Column).Value
    End If

Next i

    MsgBox Final

End Sub
```